# Transforming Data Frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with multiple variables which in turn have multiple categories. I'll like to take each category and convert them to indicator variables.

```
V1 V2 V3 V4
xc ab ty ky
xc ab ty kj
xc yi tf kj
cv yi tf kj
bg yt tg kl
bg yu yu kl
```

convert to

```
xc cv bg .....
T  F  F......
T  F  F....
T  F  F....
F  T  F....
F  F  T...
F  F  T....
```

i tried

```
newframe <- transform(oldframe, xc = to_column(oldframe$V1,'xc'))
```

where to column is

```
to_column = function(col, val){
    if (col == val)
        'TRUE'  else
        'FALSE' }
```

Comment: i just tried newframe <- transform(oldframe, xc = (oldframe[,1]=='xc')) which worked but is still a bit cumbersome for a data-set with lots of variable categories

Comment: My answer below returns a 0/1 dummy variable via one of the standard ways in R. Let me know if that works :)

Answer (score 7):

This is one standard approach to creating dummy varaibles from a categorical variable:

```
model.matrix( ~ V1 - 1, data=df)
```

df is your data.frame as shown in your question. This returns 0/1 binary as your FALSE/TRUE. Hope that helps!

Best regards,

Jay

Comment: great that helped, but can i do more than one variable at the same time?

Answer (score 5):

Building on @Jay's answer, we have this as a logical matrix.

**Logical matrix version:**

```
out <- model.matrix( ~ V1 - 1, data=dat)
out <- matrix(as.logical(out), ncol = ncol(out))
colnames(out) <- with(dat, levels(V1))

> out
        bg    cv    xc
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**All variables at once version:**

```
out2 <- sapply(dat, function(x) model.matrix( ~ x - 1))
out2 <- do.call(cbind, out2)
out2 <- matrix(as.logical(out2), ncol = ncol(out2))
colnames(out2) <- unlist(sapply(dat, levels))

> out2
        bg    cv    xc    ab    yi    yt    yu    tf    tg    ty
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
        yu    kj    kl    ky
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

If you don't want this as a full matrix like above, then you can stop with the first line, which has all the model matrices in a list, one for each variable (column) in `dat`, and convert the to a logical. This one-liner does both steps:

```
> lapply(lapply(dat, function(x) model.matrix( ~ x - 1)),
+        function(x) matrix(as.logical(x), ncol = ncol(x)))
$V1
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

$V2
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

$V3
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

$V4
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[6,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

And if the variable names are important, then we can modify this to

```
foo <- function(x) {
    mat <- matrix(as.logical(x), ncol = ncol(x))
    colnames(mat) <- levels(x)
    mat
}
lapply(lapply(dat, function(x) model.matrix( ~ x - 1)), foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the reshape package, it provides functionality to pivot data like this. There are examples of its use [at the author's homepage](http://had.co.nz/reshape/)

Comment: While this link may theoretically answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straightforward with `mtabulate` from the "qdap" package:

```
library(qdap)
mtabulate(split(mydf, 1:nrow(mydf))) > 0
#      ab    bg    cv    kj    kl    ky    tf    tg    ty    xc    yi
# 1  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 3 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 5 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 6 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#      yt    yu
# 1 FALSE FALSE
# 2 FALSE FALSE
# 3 FALSE FALSE
# 4 FALSE FALSE
# 5  TRUE FALSE
# 6 FALSE  TRUE
```

By default, `mtabulate` would tabulate the results (surprise!) so the result would be a numeric `data.frame`. You'll see, for instance, that the count of "yu" in row 6 is actually 2. To get the `logical` output you desire (just presence/absence), just compare the values obtained from `mtabulate` with zero.